# How to extract Outlook email data based on subject of the email using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have VBA code that extracts tables from Outlook emails.

I have a subfolder under "inbox" wherein all similar mails comes in.

I want to extract data based on the subject of the email, instead of having a dedicated subfolder for that particular email.

Code below.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportTable()

Cells.Clear
Dim OLApp As Outlook.Application
'Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OLApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim ONS As Outlook.Namespace
Set ONS = OLApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set myFolder = ONS.Folders("emailaddress").Folders("Inbox")
Set myFolder = myFolder.Folders("Others")
Dim OLMAIL As Outlook.MailItem
Set OLMAIL = OLApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

For Each OLMAIL In myFolder.Items
    Dim oHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set oHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim oElColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    With oHTML
        .Body.innerHTML = OLMAIL.HTMLBody
        Set oElColl = .getElementsByTagName("table")
    End With

    Dim t As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim eRow As Long

    For t = 0 To oElColl.Length - 1
        eRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        For r = 0 To (oElColl(t).Rows.Length - 1)
            For c = 0 To (oElColl(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                Range("A" & eRow).Offset(r, c).Value = oElColl(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
            Next c
        Next r
        eRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Next t
        
    'Cells(eRow, 1) = "Sender's Name:" & " " & OLMAIL.Sender
    'Cells(eRow, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
    'Cells(eRow, 1).Font.Color = vbWhite
    Cells(eRow, 1) = "Date & Time of Receipt:" & " " & OLMAIL.ReceivedTime
    Cells(eRow, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
    Cells(eRow, 1).Font.Color = vbWhite
    Cells(eRow, 1).Columns.AutoFit
        
Next OLMAIL

Range("A1").Select

Set OLApp = Nothing
Set OLMAIL = Nothing
Set oHTML = Nothing
Set oElColl = Nothing

On Error Resume Next
Range("A1:A" & Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You said ``I have a VBA script that extracts tables from outlook emails.``  How these mails are treated? They enter the inbox and the macro runs automatically? When you select one or open it and you run the macro by pressing a button? Be more specific on how you actually deal with the mails and how you want to do it.

Comment: AS of now I am manually running the macro whenever i want the data to be extracted from the emails to an excel file. What I am looking for is how do I filter the emails based on the "Subject" of the email, loop through the mail based on a particular subject and extract data only from those emails.

Comment: I believe there is at least two ways to deal with your problem. The first one, every mail that comes to the inbox or any other folder can be managed automatically and do what you tell it to do. For this approach, take a look a this [website](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/itemadd-macro/). The second way is to have a macro that is run on demand by pressing a button and do what you want. If have different subjects that needs to be treated and you choose the second way, you may have to create several buttons.

Comment: Sure I can try that out. Thankyou! But is there a way to have just one macro and filter the subject of the email and then extract data from it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with incoming emails look at the link to the website that I put in comment above.

If you want to deal with the current item, there is a few ways to do it. Here is one of the ways I found recently and it's awesome and I am using it! Click [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2021/04/21/outlook-email-templates-fillable-fields-dropdown/#close) to the website.

I have done a modification to suit your needs. If you have different subjects, it's sure that the content to be extract will also be different, so it inspects the current item and it runs a specific macro depending on the subject.

Paste the code in **ThisOutlookSession** module

```
Private WithEvents m_Inspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Private WithEvents m_Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
  
Private Sub Application_Startup()
 Set m_Inspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub
  
Private Sub m_Inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
 If TypeOf Inspector.currentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
  'Handle emails only
  Set m_Inspector = Inspector
 End If
End Sub
  
Private Sub m_Inspector_Activate()
    Dim Item As MailItem
    
    If TypeOf m_Inspector.currentItem Is MailItem Then
        Set Item = m_Inspector.currentItem
        
        With Item
            ' Display mail
            '.Display
            
            ' Mails with filled opions
            Select Case .subject
                Case "mySubject_01"
                    Call Macro_01
                    
                Case "mySubject_02"
                    Call Macro_02
                    
                Case "mySubject_03"
                    Call Macro_03
            End Select
            
            Set Item = Nothing
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou for the code! This would run every time whenever I get an email with particular subject?

Comment: What if I don't want to run the code every time an email comes in? Let's say I have 10 emails with subject line "Volume data". All these emails have information in the form of tables, and I want to extract those data from those 10 emails so that analysis can be done. So for now the code that i have does the work, but the only thing is it is not looping based on the subject line of the emails. How do I give that condition in my code that i provided above that data should be extracted from the emails in my Inbox which has the subject line as "Volume data".?

Comment: Take a look a at this [link](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/working-items-folder-selected-items/). It shows two examples how to ``Work with all items in any folder`` and ``Work with Selected items in any folder``.

Comment: Sure, thankyou. I will check it out.